# How can I resize a form in my HTML to fill the screen of a mobile device?

Tags: android, html, responsive-design

I have created an html page for login containing fields for username and password on top left corner of page. I want then when this page is viewed in Android emulator browser, only the top left part of my original page should be filling the entire page. How should I do this? How to make a webpage compatible to mobile browser.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the width and height to 100% might solve your problem, but it's difficult to guess.

Post the relevant part of your code here, then people can help easier.

Comment: It wont help. When my page runs in Internet Explorer, only about a very small portion at top left corner of screen is occupied.I want that part of the screen to be the complete screen when run on Android Emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript code below to detect browser and change the properties of html elements using `setAttribute()` on the fly. It is explained here:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domattribute.shtml

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i))  { 
        ...
}
```